# Is there a way to modify specific cells in a data.frame with an apply-statement?

Tags: r, apply

I have a data set

```
   V1  V2  V3  V4
1 0.2 0.1 0.0 0.8
2 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.0
3 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.0
4 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.1
5 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

in which each variable has one cell to which I would like to add a fraction (10 %) of the other values in the same column.

This indicates the row in each variable that should receive the bonus:

```
bonus<-c(2,3,1,4)
```

And the desired output is this:

```
   V1   V2   V3   V4
1 0.18 0.09 0.10 0.72
2 0.37 0.36 0.27 0.00
3 0.09 0.37 0.18 0.00
4 0.18 0.09 0.36 0.19
5 0.18 0.09 0.09 0.09
```

I do this with a for-loop:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(tab)){
  tab[bonus[i],i]<-tab[bonus[i],i]+sum(0.1*tab[-bonus[i],i])
  tab[-bonus[i],i]<-tab[-bonus[i],i]-(0.1*tab[-bonus[i],i])
}
```

First row in the {} adds the 0.1*sum_of_other_values to the desired cell whose index is in `bonus`, second row subtracts from all cells but the one in `bonus`.

But I need to do this with a lot of columns in a lot of matrices and am struggling with including the information from the external vector `bonus` into a loop-less function.

Is there a way to vectorise this and then `apply` it across the datasets to make it faster?

Thanks very much!

( Example data:

```
tab<-data.frame(V1=c(0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.2),
                V2=c(0.1,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.1),
                V3=c(0.00,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.1),
                V4=c(0.8,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.1))
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```r
mapply(
  function(vec, bon) { 
    more <- vec/10
    vec + ifelse(seq_along(vec) %in% bon, sum(more[-bon]), -more)
  }, asplit(tab, 2), bonus)
#        V1   V2   V3   V4
# [1,] 0.18 0.09 0.10 0.72
# [2,] 0.37 0.36 0.27 0.00
# [3,] 0.09 0.37 0.18 0.00
# [4,] 0.18 0.09 0.36 0.19
# [5,] 0.18 0.09 0.09 0.09
```

Sometimes I try to separate the *change* out of the function (such as when you want to troubleshoot the magnitude of change or some other summary statistic about it before updating the original `tab`le); if that appeals, then this can be shifted slightly:

```r
changes <- mapply(
  function(vec, bon) {
    more <- vec/10
    ifelse(seq_along(vec) %in% bon, sum(more[-bon]), -more)
  }, asplit(tab, 2), bonus)
changes
#         V1    V2    V3    V4
# [1,] -0.02 -0.01  0.10 -0.08
# [2,]  0.07 -0.04 -0.03  0.00
# [3,] -0.01  0.07 -0.02  0.00
# [4,] -0.02 -0.01 -0.04  0.09
# [5,] -0.02 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01
tab + changes
#     V1   V2   V3   V4
# 1 0.18 0.09 0.10 0.72
# 2 0.37 0.36 0.27 0.00
# 3 0.09 0.37 0.18 0.00
# 4 0.18 0.09 0.36 0.19
# 5 0.18 0.09 0.09 0.09
```

Comment: wow, fantastic! thanks very much, r2evans! neat use of the ifelse() and asplit(). Cheers!